# Django Python, Pass a dictionary and print it's content in html template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have this function just for learning and want to print out the xxxxx and yyyyy on the html page.
I have tried everything but the best I can get is aaa bbb

```
def index(request):
template = loader.get_template('bsapp/index.html')
listan = {'aaa':'xxxxxx','bbb':'yyyyyy'}
context = {
    'listan': listan
}
return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

This is the html page, how would I write it?:

```
{% for item in listan %}
    {{ item }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate your dictionary in Django as:

```
{% for key, value in listan.items %}
    {{ value }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

You can use `{{ key }}` if you want to display key as well.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much!!

Comment: I'm not understand dictionarys really. Do you also know how this dict would look like?
It's a sample from Django documentation but they don't show the list.    

<ul>
    {% for athlete in athlete_list %}
        <li>{{ athlete.name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>

Comment: Its a list of dictionaries. Django doc is pretty explanatory, go through it slowly. Also you can quickly search solutions for these trivial questions